# Regex : Match everything after first dash

Tags: regex

I have a string which contains the rego number of the car like

```
1FX9JE - 2012 Audi A3 Ambition Sportback MY12 Stronic
```

I would like to match everything except the rego number, so anything after the dash.

The regex I came up with is (php)

```
\s.[^-]*$
```

My initial regex which i came up can match anything after the dash only if the string contains only 1 dash. For example https://regex101.com/r/Jao8W0/1

However, if the string has more than 1 dash. The regex is not usable. 
For example : https://regex101.com/r/Jao8W0/2

Is there anyway for me to match anything after the first dash even though the string contains additional dash after the first dash.

Thank you

Comment: `/-(?<match>.*)/` will work as you want.

Comment: oh, why didn't I think of that. Would you like to post your answer?

Comment: What language do you use? Without the language it isn't possible to say what regex features are available for your case.

Comment: I am using regular expression in domo , a data platform, it seems to take regex from prce php.

Comment: I suggest [`-\h*+\K[^\r\n]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/Hq8hiE/2) with the m modifier.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'm not aware of any regex engine or environment that *wouldn't* support such basic feature. :)

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: now you are.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte would you mind giving an example of regex engine that doesn't support `-.*`?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk: Curious that you don't mention the named capture group (or a simple capture group) or the `\K` feature or the lookbehind. Actually, none of the answers or suggestions in comments works for all regex engines or environments. Even something like `-(.*)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
^[^-\r\n]+-\s*\K.*$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jao8W0/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `[^-\r\n]+` - matches 1+ occurrences of any character that is neither a `-` or nor a newline
- `-\s*` - matches the first `-` in the string followed by 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` - forgets everything matched so far
- `.*` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

if only has one space, you can use this pattern:

```
(?<=\-\s)(.*)
```

else if there may have more than one space, get the group(1) from match

```
(?<=\-)\s*(.*)
```

> (?<=...) Ensures that the given pattern will match, ending at the
>   current position in the expression. The pattern must have a fixed
>   width. Does not consume any characters.